# Minimum and maximum number we can store?

Tags: floating-point

Given 8 bits, out of which 1 bit is for the sign, 3 bits for the exponent and 4 bits mantissa, what is the minimum and maximum number we can store?

Can someone please explain this as I am a beginner and somewhat lost?

Comment: Anyone, please???

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about your floating-point format. Is it basically like ieee754, only with smaller ranges for the exponent and mantissa? Does it support denormals, infinites and NANs? Does it use a biased exponent? Does it have an implicit leading 1 for normalized floats?

Answer (score 0):

As @EOF says, the answer to the question depends on the specification, but we can take a guess at some of the details and follow a typical IEEE 754 style.

First, assume that infinities are supported. That means that +/-Inf could be a valid answer to the question

+Inf

```
0 111 0000
```

-Inf

```
0 111 0000
```

However, most likely infinities aren't considered a number for the purposes of the question, so now we need to decide what bias we're using. 3 is a reasonable bias. An exponent of 7 (111) indicates an infinity (or NaN, if any of the mantissa bits are non-zero), and therefore the maximum possible exponent is 6-3=3. The largest representable number is then given by

```
0 110 1111
```

Assuming that there is an implicit bit, this converts to 2<sup>3</sup> * 1.1111<sub>2</sub>=8 *  1.9375=15.5

And the smallest would be the negative of that. However, I guess the more interesting question is what is the smallest non-zero number in terms of absolute value. Assuming that subnormal numbers are supported, this is given by the minimal exponent and minimal non-zero mantissa, i.e.

```
0 000 0001
```

This converts to 2<sup>-2</sup> * 0.0001<sub>2</sub>=2<sup>-6</sup>=0.015625
Obviously, you can flip the sign bit and maintain the absolute value